# How to remotely install CentOS in a bare metal machine

Tags: centos, installation, remote, automated-install

I am from software development background, and as such not much exposure to admin aspects of the server.

I have a particular need.

From my server how can I remotely install CentOS in bare-metal machine. The machine where I intend to install the CentOS doesn't have any pre-configured OS, that is a bare machine. This machine doesn't have any external CD / DVD for installation.

Is this scenario possible.?

Comment: What is the brand of the bare-metal server ? Do you have something like an external console you can access remotely such as iDrac (DELL) or ilo (HP) ?

Comment: You use the out of band management console. Read the server's documentation.

Comment: It is HP laptop where I want to install the centOS remotely. It has 2 USB,  Lan port etc.

Answer (score 2):

> It is HP laptop where I want to install the centOS remotely.

Ship a USB pen drive with a suitably configured installation environment and have someone plug it in and configure the system to boot it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one off, @[istheEnglishWay](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/is-the-english-way)'s suggestion to use a USB stick seems like a good bet.

If you suspect you might need to do this a few times, PXE booting might be a good option to consider.

I've used [cobbler](https://cobbler.github.io/) for similar needs, and found it to be suitable, and reasonably easy to setup and use. 
It is, however, really only worth you time to do that if you feel you might do this a few times.
It is also possible to set up PXE with less overhead (especially if you can live with just having a default install pushed out each time), but install only DHCP (unless you already have something suitable) and a TFTP server.

One **big** caveat to this is you will need the laptop's wired interface to play nice, and that may not be the case (I can't speak for HP laptops, but I have had issues with lower-end Acer laptops when trying to use PXE).